# -D option to define parameter is not working in MAVEN 3 but working in MAVEN 2

Tags: maven-3

We upgrade our project to from Maven 2 to Maven 3. We had a parameter for version of the project and provide the value in maven goal. After upgrade to Maven 3, its not working.

Instead of providing -D tried --define option too, still its not able to recognize. Tried the -DnewVersion with versions:set, but it does not work when i have the complete goal. I need to run the maven goal twice. Think link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJzZvBVd18w was helpful, but do not solve the purpose.

```
<groupId>alex.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
  <version>${rel.version}</version>   
  <name>Test1</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Maven 2, following mvn command worked
mvn clean install -Drel.version=1.0.1

Same command failed in Maven 3 stating the following error
"'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ alex.test:test1:${rel.version}"

As project has dependencies I tried the following

Parent Pom

```
<groupId>alex.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Test1</name>
  <properties>
    <child1.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</child1.version>   
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
     <groupId>test</groupId>
     <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
     <version>${child1.version}</version>  
      </dependency>         
    <dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <modules>
    <module>../child1</module>      
  </modules>
```

Child Pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>alex.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>child1</artifactId>    
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>  
  <artifactId>child1</artifactId>  
  <name>child1</name>
```

while executing following command on parent project 
mvn versions:update-properties versions:set -DnewVersion=3.0-SNAPSHOT

It updated the pom.xml in both Parent and Child modules,

But following command failed with error
mvn versions:update-properties versions:set -DnewVersion=3.0-SNAPSHOT clean install

Error:
The project alex.test:child1:[unknown-version] (C:\Maven_Test\Test_Program\child1\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for alex.test:child1:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact alex.test:test1:pom:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT

1. Why -D parameter not working on version tag in Maven 3.
2. In terms of complex multinode project how to create the artifact versioning and can we handle it in maven goal ?